# Locale.getDefault() vs Locale.English main Difference android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, time, localization, timezone

I am working on android application my application running across the world so I my using local times of all around the world to calculate times of daily activities. The problem which i am facing is that when i want to get time of local country like for example when i use `Locale.getDefault()` it some times returns values in user's device language for example if a user have a device language  Arabic it will return me those values in Arabic format. my logic is design only for English numeric  characters when language changes it gives me exception of number format. there is another option which is Locale.English it returns me values in English I want to Ask that if i use `Locale.english` instead of `Locale.getDefault()` is there any thing wrong in it or I am doing it in a currect way?

Comment: `locale` is for such text translation (as you saw). I think you should check on how do you get the time, and check for local time (local not locale), so you need the time with time-offset (sometime you see it as "timezone", but such word is not always interchangeable)

Answer (score -1):

```
Locale.getDefault().toString() and context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString()
```

should return the same value.

The only major difference between the two is that the
Locale.getDefault() can be directly overridden by Locale.setDefault(locale). (Which will also affect context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString())

Comment: but my question is that Locale.getDefault() vs Locale.English does they return same values if the device languages is changed? which is best? because getDefault returning me output in user device language which i do not want.